# Sorting the properties of the object

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

My json object looks like this:

```
events:{
"2": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
}
"0": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
}
"1": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
}

}
```

I need to sort the properties of the object. Is there anyway to do this? The result should be like this:

```
events:{
"0": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
}
"1": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
}
"2": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
}

}
```

Comment: in objects, [order is not guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/575527). store them in arrays instead.

Comment: @Joseph — That should be an answer. :)

Comment: @Srikanth Kshatriy — That is an object literal, not JSON. JSON is a data serialisation format.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for an XY Problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @joeframbach yeah.. looks like a XY Problem but was looking for X's solution only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee order, like @Joseph said, it needs to be in an array:

```
var events = {
  "2": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
  },
  "0": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
  },
  "1": {
    "action": "some value",
    "property": "some value"
  }
};

var eventOrder = [];

for( var prop in events ){
  if( events.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ){
    eventOrder.push( prop );
  }
}

eventOrder.sort();
```

Note: this is going to sort by ALPHABETICAL order since you're using strings, so if you have more than 9 items, you may end up with eventOrder as [ "1", "10", "2", ... ].  If this is not desired, you could parseInt before storing in the array, and the force to string later when you're doing lookups.

Comment: This suited best for my requirement. Thanks @webnesto

Comment: There is no need to "force" a string later, `alert(events[2])` will work fine.

Comment: @RobG - you're technically right, but you're relying on JS type conversion at that point.  It is the same thing as using a "==" for evaluations and if you come down on the "===" side of the arguments there, then you'd also want to make sure you were using strings for your hash lookups.

Comment: Most do type conversion in javascript without giving it a second thought, it's a feature of the language that is there to be used. Does anyone do `obj[String(a)]` or `obj[String(fn())]` or even `String(a) + String(b)`? FWIW I only ever use `===` where it's needed, which is not often.

Answer (score 1):

in conjunction to my comment, store it this way instead: use an array, then store those indexes as ids. then you can move them around using some sorting algorithm. here' are [some samples of sorting algorithms](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) you might want to take a look

```
events:[
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "action": "some value",
        "property": "some value"
    },
    {
        "id" : 0,
        "action": "some value",
        "property": "some value"
    },
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "action": "some value",
        "property": "some value"
    }
]
```

Comment: I generally prefer to store order and data as separate elements - { events: { "foo" : { "id" : "foo", ... } }, eventOrder: [ "foo", ... ] }